# Unable to write text to disk in Design Autimation application

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm trying to store some temporary information on disk.

`File.WriteAllText(someText, filePath);`

But when running the app I get an error:

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

The path in question is

```
T:\Aces\Jobs\c59d2b7a17724f918758c90e18ee58c0\tempFile.txt
```

I can't see any illegal characters in this path. I've even had it output the path as a byte array just to double check that no invisible chars have been added, but it doesn't seem to be any.

It's strange that the error says "Illegal characters in path", but maybe it's a red herring and the problem is somewhere else?

Any suggestions? Do I have to do something special to make my forge app be able to write to disk?

Thanks!

Comment: You can test against [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-7.0)

Comment: And it's (path, contents) , not (contents, path) , see [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-7.0) - I guess `someText` _does_ contain some illegal path chars :D

Comment: Oh dang! That's a two hour mistake right there! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In addition @Fildor comment, you don't need to pass full path, the files created are stored relative to the workitem job folder.
Here `layers.txt` is created on `T:\Aces\Jobs\c59d2b7a17724f918758c90e18ee58c0`

Ex:

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText("layers.txt"))
                {
                    dynamic layers = db.LayerTableId;
                    foreach (dynamic layer in layers)
                        writer.WriteLine(layer.Name);
                }
```

Comment: Ah, I actually tried that first, but because of my mistake I was led to believe that there was something else wrong! =P Thanks for the suggestion!